# Docker Image stopped working after Updating from 4.6 to 4.8.1

Tags: docker, nginx

Had a functioning Docker Image that was running fine on Docker 4.6

After Upgrading to 4.8.1 i get : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when trying to reach it.

nginx conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
  server {
      listen 80;

      location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
     }
}
```

Docker File

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker logs:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh

10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: IPv6 listen already enabled

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

Comment: Is there anything useful in nginx `access.log` and `error.log`?

Answer (score 0):

A Reboot of my Windows solved the issue. Just restarting Docker seems not to be enough